# Why does plotting a concatenated array add a diagonal line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have three arrays, `x_left`, `x_right`, and `y`

the top subplot, I use

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(x_left, y)
plt.plot(x_right, y)
```

and for the bottom subplot,

```py
plt.plot(np.concatenate((x_left, x_right)), np.concatenate((y, y)))
```

[image: The pic two ways to plot]

Why is there a diagonal line starting at the red point in the bottom plot? How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Why are you concatenating `y` to itself?

Comment: Your two x ranges aren't contiguous; it looks like they both start at 0, and move outward from there (in different directions).  The slash is the connection between the final point of `x_left` and the first point of `x_right`.  Reversing one of the ranges (along with reversing the copy of `y` that goes with it) should fix the problem.

Comment: @MattDMo because they want a symmetric plot -- `x_left` and `x_right` have the same `y` values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because `x_left` is ordered from left to right, but `x_right` is ordered from right to left. Consider `x_left = np.linspace(-1, 0, 11)`, and `x_right = -x_left`. When you concatenate `x_left` and `x_right`, you get

```
array([-1. , -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1,  0. ,
        1. ,  0.9,  0.8,  0.7,  0.6,  0.5,  0.4,  0.3,  0.2,  0.1, -0. ])
```

Notice the jump from `0` to `1`? That's the diagonal line.

To get rid of this, sort your concatenated `x` array. Of course, you'll also need to sort the concatenated `y` array with the same order:

```
x_plot = np.concatenate((x_left, x_right))
sort_order = x_plot.argsort()

y_plot = np.concatenate((y, y))

plt.plot(x_plot[sort_order], y_plot[sort_order])
```

Here's what the plot would look like if you plotted them separately vs. by concatenating without sorting vs. concatenating and sorting like I showed above:

```
x_left = np.linspace(-1, 0, 11)
y = 1 - x_left**2

x_right = -x_left

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(11, 3.5))
ax[0].plot(x_left, y)
ax[0].plot(x_right, y)
ax[0].set_title("Plot separately")

x_plot = np.concatenate((x_left, x_right))
y_plot = np.concatenate((y, y))
sort_order = x_plot.argsort()

ax[1].plot(x_plot, y_plot)
ax[1].set_title("Plot concatenated")

ax[2].plot(x_plot[sort_order], y_plot[sort_order])
ax[2].set_title("Plot concatenated+sorted")

fig.tight_layout()
```

(for this plot, I used `y = 1 - x_left**2`, since you didn't provide your data in your question)

[image]

Comment: Splendid, thank you man, I got it. BTW, also thanks for revising my question, I don't write in English for years.